# How to set output path for .net build in Azure DevOps Pipeline

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have the following task:

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: 'XXX'
      arguments: '-c "Release" /p:Platform="x64"'
```

and I want to set the outputpath of the build so that I can publish an artifact after compiling.

```
    /p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\XXX"
```

But when I specify the output directory (--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\X') I get an error MSB3073

If I remove the output argument it works.

How can I build correctly so that I can publish the artifact or solve the output issue?

Comment: Nitro5 can you update your question to include the error message you might be experiencing?

Comment: I found another question you posted Nitro5 with more detail in it... (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71163827/azure-devops-solution-build-dotnet) I'm updating the question with additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding it to the `arguments`?

```yaml
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: 'XXX'
      arguments: '-c "Release" /p:Platform="x64" /p:OutputPath="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\XXX"'
```

Comment: yes no works 
:(

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't specify the output directory when compiling, the project will compile and place the `bin` folder in the subfolder of the project. This is the same behavior if you were to compile the solution locally. So you could publish the artifact from that folder:

```
- publish: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\path-to-my-project\bin\'
  artifact: myArtifact
```

For .NET core projects, the [command syntax for dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build) is:

```
dotnet build [options] <project | solution>
```

The syntax for the output directory is `-o <directory>` or `--output <directory>`. The important detail here is you need to wrap the output directory in quotes and additional msbuild parameters are specified as `-p:<param>="value"`

Fun tip, you can use the [`>` operator](https://yaml-multiline.info/) in YAML to represent multi-line strings, so you could represent your task this way:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: 'XXX'
    arguments: >
      -c "Release"
      -p:Platform="x64"
      -o "$(Build.artifactStagingDirectory)\XXX"
```

Also note, this being .NET Core, if you're using a Linux build agent, you'll need to use backslashes ('/') for the file path.