# Azure devops Solution build Dotnet

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

```
  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
displayName: Build X (DotNet)
inputs:
  command: 'build'
  projects: '$(X)'
  arguments: '-c "Release" /p:Platform="x64" --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\X'
```

once I adding the output (--output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\X') argument for be able to PublishArtifact after that the build results.

I got error from solution of missing's files in the Build Solution: error MSB3073

and if I remove the output is work good but I have no option to publishArtifact the results

to some 1 have suggestion how can I publish the results to artifact without output? or to solve the output issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set output path for .net build in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162590/how-to-set-output-path-for-net-build-in-azure-devops-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the `--output` parameter is available. You can alternatively build your solution using your task and add a separate powershell task to copy build directory to your requested folder. For example:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Copy code output to artifactsStagingDirectory
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'Move-Item "$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/src/solutionName/bin/Debug" "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/X"'
```